# How do I randomly select multiple distinct integers from a range in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I write a function like: `select_from(n, min, max)` which randomly select n distinct integers ranging from `min`(included) to `max`(excluded).

As I searched, all answers are for selecting one item/number from an array/range, but not multiple items. One approach I currently can think of is to create an array of integers from `min` to `max`. Then repeatedly select items from that array while after each selection delete the selected item:

```
function select_from(n, min, max) {
    var range = [];
    var result = [];

    for (var i = min; i < max; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }

    for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        var select = Math.floor(Math.random()*range.length);
        result.push(range[select]);
        range = range.splice(select, 1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Is there any efficient way? Thank you!

Comment: What about `foo`??

Comment: Which array are you selecting them from?, your `range` is an empty array so your code is broken

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Sorry mis-typed.

Comment: @Dummy I have corrected my text.

Comment: @XiaojunChen see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Modify your second for loop like this

```
for (var j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    var select = Math.floor(Math.random()*range.length);

    if (result.indexOf(range[select]) === -1)
        result.push(range[select]);
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thus the length of `result` might be less than `n`. Meanwhile, is this algorithm O(n^2), I mean the total time.

Comment: That's true considering the total time

Comment: OK I get it. But in your code, if the condition `(result.indexOf(range[select]) === -1)` is `false`, no item will be added to `result`. So the `for` loop should change to `while` and stop till the length of `result` is `n`? That means I will not know how many loops actually take place.

Comment: While loop is fine, but in this for loop case, if the condition is false, it will continue through the next iteration,  when `j` is equal to `n`, it will loop one last time (because your loop has `j <= n`, which means *as long as `j` is **not** greater than `n`, then keep looping*, then the next iteration, `j` is equal to `n+1` which will cause your loop to exit

Comment: I mean, after n iteration, the length of `result` might be less than `n`.

Comment: That's true, you can use while loop in that case, then use `result.length < n` as the condition

Answer (score 0):

How about not initializing integer array but `random()` range instead?

```js
function select_from(n, min, max) {
  var result = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min));
  }
  
  return result;
}

var numbers = select_from(100, 5, 10);
console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: **distinct integers**

Answer (score 0):

One alternative, but I have no idea of the relative performance impact, is to use splice():
This means you can keep the for loop, but are constantly mutating the `range` array:

```js
function select_from(n, min, max) {
    var range = [];
    var result = [];

    for (var i = min; i < max; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        var select = Math.floor(Math.random()*range.length);
        result.push(range.splice(select, 1)[0]);
    }
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}
select_from(10,1,11)
```

Comment: Deleting an element from a list in the middle is a really expensive operation

Comment: @Dummy maybe, but it may compare well with others; I have no idea of any relative time costs compared to checking if that value has been used already.

Comment: Time complexity wise, your solution just runs in O(n) if we don't care too much about `splice()`

Comment: @Dummy What about I use [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) to shuffle the array every time, take the last one and remove that. Although I don't know the cost either.

Comment: @XiaojunChen you still incur the same cost because you shuffle the source array on every iteration which is O(n) for that algorithm